# Wake up on LAN не включает компьютер MSI B75MA-P45 (Realtek RTL8111E)

Tags: сеть, железо, lan, windows-7

Материнская плата *MSI B75MA-P45 (MS-7798)*
Сетевая плата *Realtek RTL8111E*

Пытаюсь включить компьютер по сети прогой *WakeMeOnLan*, но реакции нет.

Какие настройки нужно сделать в BIOS и в Windows 7 (ну там в настройках сетевой что ли)?

Текущие настройки (скрины сделаны из Windows):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сетевая карта, кстати, не мигает индикаторами не в режиме сна, не при выключении...

Comment: в биосе должен стоять флаг wakeonlan в положении true (если такой есть), компьютер должен быть в состоянии S3 (сон) и выше, если память не изменяет.

Comment: А если компьютер был штатно выключен, или по причине отключения света (УПС на два компьютера, следовательно от него кабель к компьютерам не подключен), то не данная функция не сработает ?

Comment: Не могу сказать точно, вероятнее всего нет (кто-то же должен принять пакет)

Comment: Добавил скрины к вопросу...